# Український відповідник бекпекінгу, бекпекера

Tags: переклад

З пояснення вікіпедії дізнаємося, що це таке:

> [Бекпе́кінг](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3) (англ. backpacking від англ. backpack — «рюкзак») —
>   поширений в останні десятиліття термін, що позначає подорожі, які
>   здійснюються туристом (бекпекером) за невеликі гроші, найчастіше
>   принципово відмовляючись від послуг туроператорів.

Як часто буває, назви видів спорту не перекладають, але це не спорт, а спосіб подорожувати, ба навіть стиль життя, судячи з насупного визначення:

> Якщо перекласти дослівно, то «бекпекінг» (backpacking) означає
>   «рюкзак». І тут стає все зрозуміло. Це спосіб подорожі по світу з цим
>   самим «багажем за плечима». А людей, які подорожують без нічого,
>   називають «бекпекерамі». Перші «мандрівники з рюкзаком» були хіпі, і
>   з'явилися вони в Америці і Європі в 60-х роках минулого століття.

[bokosmart.com](http://bokosmart.com/turyzm/turystu-na-zamitku/2255-wcho-take-bekpeking)

Як краще українською назвати бекпекінг і бекпекера, не втрачаючи при цьому багато змісту?

Answer (score 2):

Дослівними перекладами будуть **рюкзачник** і, можливо, **наплічникар**.

Answer (score 1):

На [цьому](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/backpacking) сайті такий переклад:

> **backpacking** - **Бекпекінг; піший туризм**.

**Бекпекера** немає у перекладі, однак звідси можна утворити **піший турист** (або ж просто **турист**).

У [Кембріджському англо-російському словнику](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/backpack?q=backpacking) пропонують ще такі варіанти:

> **backpacking** noun [ U ] B1 **туристичний похід**: to go backpacking
>
> **backpacker** noun [ C ] B1 **турист**.

Comment: дякую, але не попадає. піший тут не підходить, бо бекпекери і в літаках мандрують, смисл в малому бюджеті подорожі

Comment: Хіба тоді  з Кембріджського англо-російського словника брати, тут без уточнення "піший". А туристичний похід спершу може бути і літаком, адже мета - туризм. Звідси назва бекпекера - турист.

Comment: не можна вважати "турист" відповідником, бо "бекпекер" умотивовано звужує значення "туриста", а ми "туристом" його знову розширюємо. Хіба що "бюджетний турист"? Та якось бідно виходить, в сенсі мовних засобів бідно. Шукаймо далі.